# Go back on Previous page state not current Page State in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please assist me on going back on Previous page last state not current Page State in Javascript.

Currently I am using which takes me on previous state

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.back(1); return false;">Back</a>
```

Comment: yes this is fine.. what's wrong in that.

Comment: Got the solution. Was looking for
protected void lbtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "history.go(-" + clsTMPreFiling.pageRefreshCount + ");", true);
        clsTMPreFiling.pageCount = 0;

    }...... Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Was looking for

```
protected void lbtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "history.go(-" + clsTMPreFiling.pageRefreshCount + ");", true); 
    clsTMPreFiling.pageCount = 0; 
}
```

Used aspx lable. Issue resolved.